# Scrollmagic.js "Jitter" on alternate monitors

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, navbar, scrollmagic

I am using Scrollmagic.js, which I find incredible, but I am having an issue I have never seen before...

When using the "Simple Pin" for a sticky navigation, something very odd happens.
On my (and 2 friends laptops), the "Pinned" menu, will jitter/jump while scrolling.
However, if I move my browser to a second monitor (or my friends do the same), the jitter completely disappears. I dont even have to refresh the page.

Could this be something to do with the current screens refresh rate? It really doesn't seem to like laptops, and I have checked all media queries, and even removed all my custom css. But still it will jitter on a laptop, but not a "real" monitor.

Note, this only happens when dragging the windows scroll bar, the mouse wheel works fine.

Heres my code:

```
 var controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller();

 new ScrollMagic.Scene({           
            triggerHook:"onLeave",      
            triggerElement: "#page-nav"  
        }).setPin("#page-nav").addIndicators().addTo(controller);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! :) Could you please provide a link to a minimal test case where this problem is reproducible to help identify the issue?

Comment: Heya, and thanks :)

http://scrollmagic.io/examples/basic/simple_pinning.html

If you look on their own demo page, it also happens for me. (The second stuck element)
This probably answers my question, as its even buggy on their own example. But, I dont understand how it happens on laptop, but not monitors.:(

Comment: Ages ago I found that if I add a duration, its fine... but I dont want a duration.. I want it stuck for the entire scroll (after the element hits top)

Comment: Interesting problem. I can't seem to reproduce this on my laptop or my desktop PC (both running Linux and Chrome 55 from stable and Firefox 52). What browser/OS combinations does this happen on?